# HTML tables and rowspan and colspan behavior

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working on this assignment and pretty much everything works fine, but I can't understand why the top cell does not occupy the entire space.

Also, it'd be really useful to know if I can format cells (size and such).

Here's the code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Notas de HTML</th>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Alumno</td>
                <td colspan="2">Conceptos (60%)</td>
                <td colspan="3">Procedimiento (30%)</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Actitud (10%)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Apellidos</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Examen te&oacute;rico</td>
                <td>Examen pr&aacute;ctico</td>
                <td>Pr&aacute;ctica 1</td>
                <td>Pr&aacute;ctica 2</td>
                <td>Pr&aacute;ctica 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ape1</td>
                <td>nom1</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>6.5</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ape2</td>
                <td>nom2</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To span all eight columns you need to use this:

```
<th colspan="8">Notas de HTML</th>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ycHu6/)**

And by using CSS you can format cells however you like.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now that you mentioned it.